# How can I create a menu in levelhelper?

Tags: objective-c, levelhelper

I want to create game with Spritehelper and Levelhelper. I wanted to know, how to create the menu with levelhelper.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Look through this tutorial(http://www.raywenderlich.com/4622/how-to-use-spritehelper-and-levelhelper-tutorial), they provide detailed information and have LevelHelper/SpriteHelper tutorials provided by the developer himself.

Answer (score 0):

After some research of instruments for new game I came to this conclusion:

**Level Helper 2:**

- good levels editing
- SpriteHelper support
- no UI editor (no UI controls)
- own class stack inherited from standard cocos2d classes (no way to create other nodes, not inherited from LHxxxx)
- animations editor
- physics editor

**CocosBuilder**

- is not supported by developers (last update 2 years ago)
- is universal: you can create UI and levels in it
- has some bugs, but is open source, so you can easily fix some issues
- uses default cocos2d class stack. You can instantiate any class inherited from Node
- supports relative node positioning (in percents relative to parent size)
- built in support of sprite sheets
- animations editor

**SpriteBuilder**

- new editor, based on idea of CocosBuilder (very similar to it)
- is under active development by cocos2d developers
- is universal (UI and levels)
- very good layout features
- supports only cocos2d-swift :-(
- there is some 3rd party cocos2d-x loaders of SpriteBuilder scenes, but they are not always compatible with new versions of SpriteBuilder
- animations editor
- physics editor

**Cocos Studio 1.x, 2.1**

- troubles with loading scenes from v1 in cocos2d-x v3 and above
- new version of CocoStudio (2.1 for now) is still not ready for production and doesn't support many features from v1
- supports relative node positioning (in percents relative to parent size)
- animations editor